# How do I prompt for a CSV user input on my on-start event for my form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

at work, we're trying to build a database to get an output of all kinds of data from different excel tables (items in stock, sales per week, price, etc) into one table by using the ItemID as primary key for all the tables and as a user input for the queries.

My goal is to let the user enter multiple itemIDs seperated by commas and get back a table with multiple rows (one for each item).

I have now created a form with all the fields I need and have used one of my queries that I implemented before as my data source.
I'm trying to write some code for my On-Start event and have used an example someone posted online regarding entering multiple parameters:

```
Option Compare Database

Const record source = Query01



Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim m As String

m = InputBox("Enter itemID (numeric), separated by comma", "itemID")

If m <> "" Then

Me.RecordSource = record_source & " where itemID in (" & m & ");"

Else

Me.RecordSource = record_source

End If

End Sub
```

For the line:

```
Me.RecordSource = record_source & " where SKU in (" & m & ");"
```

I get the error

```
Run-Time error '2580'
The record source 'where SKU in (" & m & ");' specified on this form or report does not exist.
```

Do I need to declare my record source differently in the second line? Do I need to somehow specify which table I get my "itemID" field out of? The Query01 that I put as my data source gets fields out of three different tables.

Thank you so much for your help!
Cheers!

Comment: Query01 should probably be in quotes at the very top, `= "Query01"`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by using the Filter-method instead and just deleting the declaration in line 2 since the data source was already defined in the properties sheet before.
My VBA code:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim m As String

m = InputBox("Enter itemID (numeric), separated by comma", "itemID")
If m <> "" Then
     Me.Filter = "itemID in (" & m & ")"
      Me.FilterOn = True
Else
     Me.FilterOn = False
End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps anyone encountering a similar problem.
Cheers!